# regular expression mysql

Tags: regex

I am writing a mysql select with regxp like this

`SELECT name FROM employees WHERE name REGEXP '^A'`

what is the regular expression syntax for this:

any record that contains `gmail.com`

thanks

Comment: `gmail\.com`. Pick one of the regular expression references from here <http://www.bing.com/search?q=regexp%20reference> and peruse it.

Comment: Follow @Madbreaks advice. Regular expression is an overkill for what you're aimming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a REGEXP here:

```
SELECT name FROM employees WHERE name LIKE '%gmail.com%';
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
REGEXP '@gmail\.com$'
```

Comment: Note, this is more strict than merely "contains" - this requires that the value be found at the end of the string.

Comment: ...and is preceded by `@` for that matter